# Drupal install on localhost asks for FTP info

Tags: ftp, drupal-7, localhost

I'm running Drupal 7.4 on localhost, and I've downloaded some themes/modules but I'm unable to install them.  I go to administration/modules, for example, select 'Upload a module or theme archive to install', choose the tar.gz from my file system, and before the install I'm asked for a FTP user and password and can not advance.

I'm working locally, so I'm thinking maybe I made some mistake during the install.  How can I correct this?  I have to do a lot of testing on local before moving the site to a server.

Comment: You can post your own answer as an accepted answer to this question.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83432/what-is-the-best-way-to-answer-your-own-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://drupal.org/node/1177884).  All I have to do is place the modules/themes inside drupal_folder/sites/default/modules or themes and that's it.

Thanks @nmc

Comment: It still seems like it should accept it from the web form.  Is this a Drupal bug or misconfiguration?

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when `sites/default` folder is not owned by the user that executes the install script. Make sure the folder `sites/default` is **owned** by the apache user (from your drupal root):

*Ubuntu*:

```
chown www-data sites/default
```

*Fedora*:

```
chown apache sites/default
```

Comment: If it won't work, try to `sudo chown www-data sites/default -R` and  `sudo chown www-data sites/all -R`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your not able to install the module, because the lack of a ftp connection, it's possible to use the old fashion way.
The other solution has described it, but it's not correct for a 100%.

If you want to do it the drupal way, you need to install the modules/themes to

drupalfolder/sites/all/modules
or
drupalfolder/sites/all/themes

if you are having a multi-installation of drupal, then:

drupalfolder/sites/domain_name/modules
or
drupalfolder/sites/domain_name/themes